# Allow user to type in decimal point as first character in numeric only field when value is highlighted JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function for my input fields that allows
numneric values only, one decimal point, two decimal values after decimal, backspace and delete key. User can also type .5 or 5. which will update to 0.5 / 5.00 onBlur. **My current issue is when the whole field value is highligted user cannot type the decimal point as the first character**,

[image]

**they have to first press delete/backspace, and only then can decimal point (period key) be entered as the first character.** This is one extra keystroke I would like to remove in that situation. I would like it to be possible to type .5 in this case, without having to delete the value first (feature request).

This is my current implementation

```
function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
   var number = el.value.split('.');
   //allow backspace
   if (charCode == 8 ) {
       return true;
   }
   //numbers only
   if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))   {
       return false;
   }    
   if (number.length > 1 && charCode == 46 ) {
       return false;
   }
   //get the carat position
   //2 decimal values after decimal point (and only one decimal character)
   var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
   var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");
   if (caratPos > dotPos && dotPos > -1 && (number[1].length > 1)) {
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}

function getSelectionStart(o) {
   return o.selectionStart
}
```

Typing values like 5. isnt an issue when field is highlighted. It works as intended. Its only when "." is the first typed character that is the problem in this case.

How can I include `charCode == 190 && charCode == 110` so they can be typed in anytime (whether field is highlighted or not but only once)

**Trying Daut's suggestion**

```
$(document).ready(function () {           

 $("input:text, form").on('keydown', function (e) {

    if ((e.keyCode == 190 || e.keyCode == 110)) {

        this.value = "0.";
    }
 });
});
```

This attempt allows one to type one decimal point over a highlighted value, but this happens for every input even when on has typed 5. which will then revert to 0., how can I filter that out for this to only happen when decimal is the first character that has been typed..

Comment: Maybe you should just add a zero in front of the comma / dot as soon as it is clicked, and not on blur.

Comment: current issue I have with that is, its appending 0 even when I type in 5. -> it will change to 0.. How can I filter this out? With your solution I would only like this append to happen if decimal is the first character being typed over a highlighted value i.e if another value has already been typed then don.t add zero. Lemme add that current attempt, you might see something I am missing from that.

Comment: What makes things even more complicated is if only part of the current value is marked.